# Deleting all the CloudWatch rules using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

We have ton of cloudwatch rules that we need to get rid of, I was working on a python script, to delete all the CloudWatch rules , but I could only find the delete rule for a specific rule on boto3 website, but I want to delete all the rules we have.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('events')
response = client.delete_rule(
    Name='string'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in two stages.

1. Get the list of `Name` of all the rules you have using [list_rules](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.list_rules)
2. Use iteration to delete all your rules, one by one, using using [delete_rule](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.delete_rule).

```
client = boto3.client('events')

rule_names = [rule['Name'] for rule in client.list_rules()['Rules']]

for rule_name in rule_names: 
   response = client.delete_rule(Name=rule_name)
   print(response)
```

Depending on how many rules you actually have, you may need to run `list_rules` multiple times with `NextToken`.

Comment: I am getting the error, 
'errorMessage":An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteRule operation:Rule can't be deleted since it has targets."
Any idea on how we can include the deletion of targets as well in the code.? TIA.

Comment: @figuring Get list of targets, and iterate over them to delete them.

Comment: I am not sure how to list targets, I am not able to find any official documentation to get a list of all the targets.

Answer (score 1):

As CloudWatch Event Rule usually has at least one target, you need to:

1. Get list of your rules using [list_rules](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.list_rules) method;
2. Loop through the list of rules and within each iteration:

   - Get list of rule's targets' IDs using [list_targets_by_rule](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.list_targets_by_rule) method;
   - Remove targets using [remove_targets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.remove_targets) method;
   - Remove the rule using [delete_rule](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.delete_rule) method.

So the resulting script will look like this:

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('events')
rules = client.list_rules()['Rules']

for rule in rules:
    rule_targets = client.list_targets_by_rule(
        Rule=rule['Name']
    )['Targets']
    target_ids = [target['Id'] for target in rule_targets]
    remove_targets_response = client.remove_targets(
        Rule=rule['Name'],
        Ids=target_ids
    )
    print(remove_targets_response)
    delete_rule_response = client.delete_rule(
        Name=rule['Name']
    )
    print(delete_rule_response)
```